# Loading from Core Data where and when?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am exploring Core Data and was doing some examples from youtube. After doing a couple I felt ready to implement Core Data into my game app. 
Now, just a quickie,the game is turn-based and you have 24 hours to complete your turn so you can have multiple games at the same time.
First, I want to know if my approach is the correct one:
-I'm using CoreData to store the current game important factors (score, turn, expiration date, match ID)
-I want to load the "saved" games (or the ones in progress) into a TableView and then when the user clicks it loads the GameViewController with the variables from that matchID.
As far as saving, I think I have the correct code, however I came across a wall when trying the load:

```
func loadCurrentGame()
    {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        do {
            try context.fetch(MatchData.fetchRequest()) //How to filter to current game and load it's variables?
        }
        catch {
            print("Error Loading Data: \(error)")
        }

    }

    func saveCurrentGame()
    {
        let dateOfSave = Date()

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let thisMatch = MatchData(context: context)
        thisMatch.isrealtime = isRealTime
        print ("is Real Time: \(thisMatch.isrealtime)")
        thisMatch.matchid = currentMatchID
        print ("match ID: \(String(describing: thisMatch.matchid))")
        thisMatch.myscore = Int16(score)
        print ("Score: \(thisMatch.myscore)")
        thisMatch.turnexpdate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: Int(timeToAnswer), to: dateOfSave)
        print ("exp Date: \(String(describing: thisMatch.turnexpdate))")

        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
    }
```

The function loadCurrentGame is in the GameViewController, however I don't know how to pass the data from another view controller (the one with the tableview). How do I tell the view controller "Hey, this is match ID XYZ, now look for that in core data and load the values form that particular instance" ?
Also, looking at the question now that I asked it, I'm having doubts about using core data to store the expiration date, is it possible to do something with this? (Like alert the user when their turn is about to expire, or auto-abandon a game once your turn expired due to inactivity?)

Comment: In GameViewController DidSelect of tableview you can pass selected data to another target viewcontoller.

Comment: Hi Bucket, Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate on this? do you know of any examples out there that I could follow?

Comment: Can you share sample code ?